# why after pip install pelican or easy_install pelican, failed?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pelican

here is the problem

```
Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
        do_download,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
        self.session,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
        download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
        for chunk in resp_read(4096):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
        chunk_size, decode_content=False):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
        data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
        data = self._fp.read(amt)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 567, in read
        s = self.fp.read(amt)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
        data = self._sock.recv(left)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
        return self.read(buflen)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len)
    SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing debug log for failure in /home/eason/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: can you add the debug log stored in /home/eason/.pip/pip.log here ?

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to read error messages:

```
 SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

It means that the server didn't respond anything for some time. The server might be busy or bugged. You should try to install again later.

You might want to call pip with a bigger timeout value if you have a lot of latency.

```
pip --default-timeout=120 install ...
```

It will timeout after 120 seconds of waiting. The default should be 60 seconds.

Check the pip's documentation here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html